# Porque sale un '[Object]' al pasar de xml a json?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, xml, jsonobject

he estado tratando de convertir desde un achuvo XML a JSON con xml2js y NodeJS, pero en cierto punto me sale como [Object], trate de solucionarlo con [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019447/passing-xml-file-to-xml2js-with-node-js) y [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238493/xml2js-how-is-the-output) pero no funciono.
En fin aqui esta el codigo

```
function parseXml() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parser=new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray:false, mergeAttrs : true});
    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/2020-1.xml', function (er, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
            var extrated="";
            extrated=result['body']['Facultad'];
            if (er) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(extracted);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Olvidenlo, no habia leido la documentacion completa, resulta que al imprimir tiene una especie de limite a 2 objetos, lo que hay que hacer es aumentar ese limite
Si quieren ver mas a detalle la [documentacion de xml2js es esta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) asi quedo el codigo por si acaso aun asi, si hay un metodo mas corto haganmelo saber

```
function parseXml() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parser=new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray:false, mergeAttrs : true});
    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/2020-1.xml', function (er, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
            var extrated="";
            const inspect=require('eyes').inspector({maxLength: false});
            //extrated=result['body']['Facultad'];
            //const complete=inspect(result);
            if (er) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(inspect(result));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

}